# Single Vue list with draggable components in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuedraggable

I wanted to see if I can get some guidance from the community on how I might be able to take on this approach and render the list properly.

**So here is what I'm attempting to do**:

- Have one single list
- Split the drag lists by pulling the objects arrays.

So here is my `Vue.js` app:

```
new Vue({
    name: 'o365-edit-modal-wrapper',
    el: '#o365-modal-edit-wrapper',
    data: function() {
        return {
            list: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.get_array_of_post_objects(this.list, 'applications');
        console.log(this.list);
    },
    methods: {
      get_array_of_post_objects(list, slug) {
          let apps_list = list;
            wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
                const Posts = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
                    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'fh/v1/menus/' + slug,
                });
                const all_posts = new Posts();
                all_posts.fetch().then(function(posts) {
                    apps_list.push(posts.data);
                });
            });
            return apps_list;
        },
        onMove({ relatedContext, draggedContext }) {
            const relatedElement = relatedContext.element;
            const draggedElement = draggedContext.element;
            return (
                (!relatedElement || !relatedElement.fixed) && !draggedElement.fixed
            );
        },
    },
    computed: {
        dragOptions() {
            return {
                tag: 'div',
                group: 'o365apps',
                disabled: !this.movable,
                ghostClass: "ghost",
            };
        },
    },
});
```

- Inside the app, I have a single `list: []` which is the empty array.
- Inside my methods, I have a GET method that retrieves an object with two arrays inside which are selected and available.
- Inside the `created()` call, I am outputting the list as `console.log(this.list);` and this is the response that I get:

[image]

**The problem**:

Previously, I had two lists and it just didn't seem efficient enough at all, would it be possible to v-for on an array inside the object?

Let's say that one of my draggable components looks like this:

```
<draggable class="list-group" v-model="list" v-bind="dragOptions" :move="onMove">
    <button class="button is-fullwidth is-flex list-group-item o365_app_handle level is-mobile" v-for="app in list" :key="app.order">
        <div class="level-left">
            <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <img :src="app.icon_url" />
            </span>
            <span>{{app.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="level-right is-hidden-desktop">
            <span class="icon has-text-primary is-clickable" @click="mobileClickAdd(index)">
              <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </button>
</draggable>
```

Is it possible to somehow target `v-for="app in list"` as 'v-for="app in list.(available array)"`? All help would be appreciated!

This is what I'm currently getting:
[image]

But it should be three of the object names:
[image]

Comment: do you need the original list to be an array? What are you using the original array for ? It looks like all you need is the root object that you get back with the available/selected.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal, the ultimate goal is to save the selected `id:` from each object on the selected side inside the database, so ultimately, I don't know if I even need the original array, but I wanted to include that, since I wouldn't know how to loop through the v-for since I have two `draggable` calls. So selected will extract all the `id:` items `onEnd` and then save to DB as a:{[343, 3423]}, etc.. but that's later on - I  am just confused on how to pass in each array now to each draggable item.

Comment: Would you know how I can use the root object to grab the data seperately inside my HTML without the list?

Comment: if you let the original list be an object `list: {}` you can then modify the v-for to `v-for="availableApps in list.available"` and likewise in a second column `v-for="selectedApps in list.selected"`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback man! Would I need to adjust my method that fetched my object? I'm getting a `apps_list.push is not a function` response now.

Comment: not sure what you have but based off the screenshots `apps_list  = posts.data` would be the way